# Simple fragment example of incrementing a variable using ViewModel and LiveData - variable always null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-architecture-components

**Note: I'm new to coding and I am trying to follow a simple example along the lines of the title.**

Everything seems to be going well, except I'm having trouble incrementing the variable in the `onClick()` method in `Tab1Fragment`. The value of the `value` variable always comes up `null`.

I think, this has something to do with mixing `Interger` with `LiveData<Integer>` but I'm not sure what to do with it. I've tried all sort of methods to convert one to the other and back to *get/store* the results. The guide i was following ([link](https://medium.com/@ogieben/basics-of-viewmodel-and-livedata-4550a34c19f3)) uses the `.setValue()` method but android studio won't let me use that method.

I would love input on fixing this, or even just a link to a super simple tab fragment tutorial that I could copy paste into a project and examine how this all works. I'm sure there's an easier method to accomplish this task, but I want to understand how to use this concept for future projects.

Thanks.

**Tab1Fragment.java**

```java
package com.example.android.tabsharer;

import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";

    public SharedViewModel model;

    public LiveData<Integer> score;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment, container, false);

//      Get the viewmodel
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);

//      Create observer to update the fragment
        TextView score1 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.score1);

        final Observer<Integer> scoreObserver = new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer newScore) {
                //Update the textview that holds the score
                score1.setText(newScore);
            }
        };

//      Observe the live data
        model.getScore().observe(getActivity(), scoreObserver);

// Create the button in java, set listener on it, increment score, and store to viewmodel
        final Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.editScore1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//              Basically every version of this comes up as null
                Integer value = model.getScore().getValue();
                if (value != null){
                    model.storeScore(++value);
                }
                else {
                    model.storeScore(0);
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

**SharedModelView.java**

```java
package com.example.android.tabsharer;

import android.app.Application;
import android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;

public class SharedViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public static final String TAG = "SharedViewModel";

    private MutableLiveData<Integer> mScore = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public SharedViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public Integer storeScore(Integer score) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Score is being stored is " + mScore);
        mScore.setValue(score);
        return score;
    }

    public LiveData<Integer> getScore() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Score is being retrieved");
        if (mScore == null){
            mScore = new MutableLiveData<>();
            mScore.setValue(0);
        }
        return mScore;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.android.tabsharer;

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public SharedViewModel model;

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting.");

        model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel.class);

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "TAB1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "TAB2");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your problems is with two things here,**

---

**Issue 1:**(Optional)

```
// Observe the live data
model.getScore().observe(getActivity(), scoreObserver);
```

You're using observer inside of `Fragment` & so that you should use it's `LifeCycle` for observing like this:

```
// Observe the live data
model.getScore().observe(this, scoreObserver);
```

---

**Issue 2:** is that you're using `Integer` as wrapper inside of `LiveData` which is not initializing during this method:

```
public LiveData<Integer> getScore() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Score is being retrieved");
    if (mScore == null){//This code won't execute because you've initialized it globally.
        mScore = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mScore.setValue(0);
    }
    return mScore;
}
```

so, try changing `Interger` to `int` & it'll be initialized with **default value 0**.

Because `Integer` will be **`null`** here :

```
// Basically every version of this comes up as null
Integer value = model.getScore().getValue();
```

Solution : Change `private MutableLiveData<Integer> mScore = new MutableLiveData<>();` to `private MutableLiveData<int> mScore = new MutableLiveData<>();` *(It'll show error to everywhere you're using LiveData, so change it to int there)*

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can see what you're saying about issue 1. With issue 2 however, I originally tried to use MutableLiveData<int> in declaring mScore, but it tells me it would not accept primitive int type and offered to convert it to Integer, and that's how I ended up with that there.

Comment: I was trying different ways to potentially input Integer to the onClick method in fragment, unwrap it to int and do my incrementation, and then re-wrap it to Integer to make the LIveData happy but I'm new enough I'm not sure what methods would do that. Also, with modelview scenarios, is it best to do the increment function in the model view, or to do the increment function in the fragment and store the result to the modelview?

Comment: I actually figured it out. Issue #1 works just fine with getActivity. In my understanding of the docs, the viewmodel belongs to the main activity and you refer to the owner of the viewmodel when declaring the model because it would otherwise get destroyed with the fragment on UI changes.

Comment: This is what my onClick ended up looking like. I needed to use model.mScore.etc to get my function to work. I was only using model.etc which is why it never gave me the option to use setValue before.
`
@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Integer score = model.mScore.getValue();

                if (score != null) {
                    model.mScore.setValue(score + 1);
                }
                else {
                    model.storeScore(1);
                }
            }
`

Comment: okay, so clearly you'd problem with your logic, not with `ViewModel` or `LiveData`